# Launch a ROS Node with an specific IP

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I've been publishing messages to a simulated Bebop2 launching the node with this command`roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1` . I am trying to write a python script in order to do the same using this `rospy.init_node("bebop_driver" )` , but I cant find the way to specify the ip.

These are the commands I am using to run the simulation.

```
sphinx /opt/parrot-sphinx/usr/share/sphinx/drones/bebop2.drone

roslaunch bebop_driver bebop_node.launch ip:=10.202.0.1
```

Once the drone is successfully simulated I use this command for takeoff

```
rostopic pub --once bebop/takeoff std_msgs/Empty
```

Here is my ***bebop_node.launch***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <arg name="namespace" default="bebop" />
   <arg name="ip" default="10.202.0.1" />
   <arg name="drone_type" default="bebop2" /> <!-- available drone types: bebop1, bebop2 -->
   <arg name="config_file" default="$(find bebop_driver)/config/defaults.yaml" />
   <arg name="camera_info_url" default="package://bebop_driver/data/$(arg drone_type)_camera_calib.yaml" />
       <node pkg="bebop_driver" name="bebop_driver" type="bebop_driver_node" output="screen">
           <param name="camera_info_url" value="$(arg camera_info_url)" />
           <param name="bebop_ip" value="$(arg ip)" />
           <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_file)" />
       </node>
       <include file="$(find bebop_description)/launch/description.launch" />

</launch>
```

This is the python I am trying to use in order to move the drone by publishing messages to the ***cmd_vel*** topic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib;roslib.load_manifest('bebop_driver')

import rospy

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

import sys

speed = float(sys.argv[1])
time = float(sys.argv[2])

print ("Adelante")

if speed != "" and speed > 0 : 

   print ("Velocidad =" , speed , "m/s")

else:

   print ("Falta parametro de velocidad o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 :

   print ("Tiempo = ",time, "s")

else:

   print ("Falta parametro de tiempo o el valor es incorrecto")

if time != "" and time > 0 : 

  print ("Publishing")

  pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)

  rospy.init_node("bebop_commander" )


  twist = Twist()
  twist.linear.x = speed; twist.linear.y = 0; twist.linear.z = 0;                      
  twist.angular.x = 0;  twist.angular.y = 0;  twist.angular.z = 0; 

  pub.publish(twist)


rospy.spin()
```

Comment: `ip` is a launch file argument. This means it is only handled by roslaunch. Please add the launch file to find out whats done there with the argument.

Comment: I ve been using that ip in order to send commands to the drone but that was using bash. Can’t figure out how to do the same with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `ip:=10.202.0.1` to your command you are setting a launch file argument. Checking the called launch file shows

```
<param name="bebop_ip" value="$(arg ip)" />
```

which means the argument is used to set the parameter `bebop_ip`. This can be also achieved in python like:

```
rospy.set_param('bebop_ip', '10.202.0.1')
```

You can find the documentation at the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Setting_parameters). Note that setting parameters also can be done in [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters#Setting_Parameters) or by [command-line](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_set).

**Update:**

Since you are trying to command a running driver, you should change the name of your *commander* because two nodes of the same name are not possible:

```
rospy.init_node("bebop_commander")
```

Also you need to add the driver name to params and topics like

```
rospy.set_param('/bebop_driver/bebop_ip', '10.202.0.1')
```

and

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('/bebop_driver/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
```

to address the running driver correctly.

Comment: I added the line to my python script but I am not getting any movement from the drone, but I am getting no error though.I added the python script in my question for extra information.

Comment: You are initializing a new node called `bebop_driver`. This does not start the node of the `bebop_driver`. This means the driver to send commands to the drone is not running. Try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question with the commands I am using to simulate and launch the node.I am trying to publish to the ***cmd_vel*** topic using the python script in order to move the drone

Comment: You cant run two nodes called `bebop_driver` simultaneously. What are you trying to achieve with your approach starting the python script with a node called like the already running driver?

Comment: It should only publish to the _cmd_vel_ topic , I understand that `pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)` should do that , but if I dont include `rospy.init_node("bebop_driver")`  I receive this error : `raise ROSException("ROS node has not been initialized yet.Please call init_node() first")`, even though the node does appear when I run `rosnode list`

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize the node you are sending your commands. But don't name it like the already existing driver. Change the name like `rospy.init_node("bebop_commander")`.